# How can I create a filter defining which invisible files to un-hide?

Tags: macos, htaccess

I want to expose `.htaccess` is the OSX GUI UI, but not other files that should be "invisible." Any ideas?

Comment: You have failed to mention any details, like are you doing this for the OS, or a specific application, or what.  Please add more detail and you might even be rewarded with an answer.

Comment: I don't know how to be more specific, OSX GUI UI is the OSX GUI. I guess you could call it the Finder, does that help?

Answer (score 0):

It would actually surprise me if OS X has this functionality built in, but maybe you can use some third party add-on like Path Finder or TotalFinder.

I don't know if they can do it, but you can always send a feature request to the author.